# Error in KableExtra when adding percentage signs in cells

Tags: r, latex, kableextra

I have the following table in an RMarkdown file using the `kableExtra` package

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

type <- c('Portfolio','Benchmark','Excess')
oct <- c("0.121",'0.108','1.32')
nov <- c('0.29','0.265','2.44')
dec <- c('0.315', '0.276','3.9')
q4 <- c('0.727','0.65','7.69')


data.frame(type,oct,nov,dec,q4) %>% 
  kable(format='latex',caption="Portfolio Income and Market Value, Q4 2020 \\label{Table2}",
        col.names = c('',"Oct-20*","Nov-20",'Dec-20',"Q4-20"), booktabs = T, escape = FALSE) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position"), font_size = 7) %>% 
  row_spec(0,bold=T,color = 'white', background = '#7c3042') %>% 
  row_spec(3,bold=T) %>% 
  column_spec(1:4, width = '1.5cm') %>% 
  footnote(general = "*Return earned over the last 10 days of October only.")
```

Works fine, but when I try to add a percentage sign (%) to each of the observations in my dataframe I get the following error when I try to knit my document

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate
```

Is there a way to add percentage labels to selected cells within my dataframe? TIA!

Comment: in latex, the `%` symbol needs to be escaped with a backslash, so try using this instead:  `"\%"`

Comment: @dww strange, when I try that I get the following error. ```Error: '\%' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\%" Execution halted```

Comment: you need to escape \ in R so we end up with a double escape in the R code `"\\%"`

Comment: Thanks @dww that works. One more thing, is there a way to bold just the % sign within my cell? Tried ```"textbf{\\%}"``` but that didnt really work